# How does dplyr filter works in R?

Tags: r, plyr

I want to filter only the rows that are less than 10 units away form the point (1,1). My dataframe has two columns, x and y.

This is what I have tried:

```
filter(df, dist( rbind(c(1,2), c(x,y)) ) < 10 )
```

But, this is not working. It always returns a 0 row result, although I know that it should return a couple of rows. How can I debug this? I would like to print every value passed to x and y in every iteration.

Per request, this is the output of dput(head(df)):

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show some data (perhaps `dput(head(df))`).

Comment: @r2evans I updated my answer with the output.

Comment: `filter` is vectorized - it doesn't work one row at a time so it's getting a big matrix as the result of your `dist` call. There is no iteration (well, the iterations are buried in C code).

Comment: `fields::rdist` can do this simply: `df %>% filter(fields::rdist(df, data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)) < 10)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use your data but it is not affected by the filter. So I will create something random:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df <- data_frame(x = sample(20, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                 y = sample(20, size = 20, replace = TRUE))
head(df)
# Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#       x     y
#   <int> <int>
# 1    19    19
# 2    19     3
# 3     6    20
# 4    17    19
# 5    13     2
# 6    11    11
```

The problem is that `dplyr::filter` requires a vector of logical. If you manually check the return of `dist(...)`, it is returning an "n-by-n" array. It is not clear how exactly `filter` should presume to use that.

If your data really is just one point (`c(1, 2)`), then you need to manually calculate the distance between the known point and the variables of the data.frame, such as:

```
filter(df, sqrt( (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 ) < 10)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#       x     y
#   <int> <int>
# 1    10     1
# 2     3     5
```

(I'm assuming euclidean distance here.) If you have more dimensions and/or a slightly different distance equation, the application should be straight-forward.

If you are instead interested in the distance between all points in `df` (as your call to `dist` implies), then you may need to use `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` and some trickery. Or perhaps do an outer join between these (`df`) points and other points.